# How to refer parent account while creating an account

Tags: apex, sobject, sobjectfield

I need to display the account name with a slash between account name and the parent account name , if the parent account field is filled. I tried to do that using SObjectType methods. But couldn't do it. I am facing:

> Invalid relationship fromo account to account.

Also if I removed `getSobject('Account')` I am facing:

> null pointer exception.

Here is my code.

```
if(wrp.mySObject.getSObject('Account').getSObject('Parent').get('Name')!=null){
    wrp.mySObject.put('Name',wrp.mySObject.get('Name')+'/'+wrp.mySObject.getSObject('Account').getSObject('Parent').get('Name'));
}
```

Here wrp is the instance of my wrapper class and mySObject is the SObject variable used in that class. Please just tell me the right way to do it generally. I will implement the same according to my code.

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Comment: Please find my updated question. Forgot to add the exception i am facing

Comment: Have you gone through https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm

Comment: yes but couldn't sort out the problem unfortunately

Comment: does your query select parent account ? can you provide your SOQL

Answer (score 0):

You could take much clear approach using SOQL query. Given a sample approach.

```
Set<Id> AccountIds = new Set<Id>();
//capture account Ids

Map<Id, Account> mapAccount = Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, Name, ParentId, Parent.Name From Account WHERE Id IN:AccountIds]);

for(Id accountId:mapAccount.keySet())
{
    Account acct = mapAccount.get(accountId);

    //here loop through the wrapper and put names
    wrp.mySObject.put('Name',acct.Name+'/'+acct.Parent.Name);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a Process that updates the Account. The process would run when the account is created. It would then check if the Parent Account is not null. If that field is not null it will update the Account Name with the following formula.

```
[Account].Name & '/' & [Account].Parent.Name
```

This way you avoid unneeded code.